# 24 balls packed in 2 packs, 4 pack and 6 packs

Tags: probability

24 balls can be packed in 2 packs, 4 packs or 6 packs or any combinations thereof.  How many different packing combinations are there?

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of systematic listing and counting. We could make things look easier by glueing pairs of balls together. Then we would have $12$ "Balls" and would be dealing with "packs" of $1$, $2$, and $3$.  But we won't do that.

We begin the listing.

(i) $4$ "six-packs". There is only $1$ way to do this (we are assuming the balls are identical).

(ii) $3$ six-packs. That leaves $6$ balls. We can use $1$ four-pack, or $0$,   for a total of $2$ choices. In each case the number of two-packs is determined.

(iii) $2$ six-packs. That leaves $12$ balls. We can use $3$ four-packs, or $\dots$, a total of $4$ choices.

(iv) $1$ six-pack.

(v) $0$ six-packs.

We leave the counting of the last two cases to you. Then add up.

**Remark:** If we had the same problem with $200$ balls, it would be worthwhile to develop some "theory." However, that theory would be based on the solid concrete counting experience we get by looking at smallish examples, such as this one.